# flutter lists checking and replacing an entry in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list in a Provider that I'm adding to using the following code:

```
context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.add(Entries(
                                  text: 'Specific Entry 01',
                                  logID: 'SELECT ENTRY'));
```

because I'm adding so many variables to the list, I've included a logID variable so I can use it to find the specific entry in other parts of my code.

Now when the user selects another entry from the list, I first want it to check if the logID is already on the list, and if it is replace it or create a new Entry.

here is what I have so far.

```
onTap: () 
{if(context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.contains(logID == 'SELECT ENTRY')){
context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.replaceRange(index, index + 1, replacements)
}else{
context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.add(Entries(
                                  text: 'Specific Entry 01',
                                  logID: 'SELECT ENTRY'));
}
```

I think I'm on the right track using .contains and .replaceRange but am unsure how to implement the code to make it work.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below code:

```
// index which have the logId as 'SELECT ENTRY'
// will return -1 if there's no element with 'SELECT ENTRY' logId
final index = entriesList.indexWhere((entry) => entry.logID == 'SELECT ENTRY');

if (index != -1) {
   // update
   entriesList[index].text = newText;
} else {
   // insert
   entriesList.add(Entries(text: 'Specific Entry 01', logID: 'SELECT ENTRY'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this part of code:

```
if(context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.contains(logID == 'SELECT ENTRY')
```

use this one:

```
if(context.read<LogProvider>().LogInfoList.logID.contains('SELECT ENTRY')
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below and let me know.

```
//either this
final element = LogInfoList.firstWhere((item) => item['logID'] == 'SELECT ENTRY', orElse: () => null);
//or this
final element = LogInfoList.firstWhere((item) => item.logID == 'SELECT ENTRY', orElse: () => null);

if (element != null){
     LogInfoList.remove(element);
}else{
     LogInfoList.add(Entries(text: 'Specific Entry 01',
                              logID: 'SELECT ENTRY'));
 }
```